# Does a new path need specified for Opera using RemoteWebDriver 2.35.0 vs 2.34.0?

Tags: python, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm attempting to upgrade to selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0 from 2.34.0.

My grid setup:
Hub in both cases kept at new 2.35 version:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role hub

Node:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig localNodeConfig.json

json file contains:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "opera",
      "platform": "VISTA",
      "maxInstances": 1,
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "maxSession": 1,
    "port": 4447,
    "host": ip,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubHost": localhost
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run my tests (creating new driver by: `remote_webdriver = webdriver.Remote( command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities={'browserName' : 'opera'} )` I get other browsers instead. The tests run just fine, but in chrome or internet explorer.

If I run with 2.34.0 with the same config.json etc then I get opera (12.16) opening as expected.

I'm setting env variable:
SET OPERA_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Opera\Opera.exe
which is where my opera is, not the other browsers!

Any help most welcome.

Edit: In the node command window I can see:

15:01:20.870 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=opera}]
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.35.1.0
showing I'm requesting the right browser but not getting it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue of Selenium 2.35 https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6094
Please wait for next release.